# Как можно через docker compose прописать, чтобы логи писались в файл приложения, а не внутри контейнера

Tags: java, docker

Хотелось бы ,чтобы логи spring boot приложения писались в файл приложения , а не в docker контейнере и настроить архивацию. Как это можно сделать через docker compose?

Comment: Что значит _логи писались в файл приложения_?

Answer (score 1):

Отмапьте папку для лог файлов на файловую систему хоста через `volumes:`.

Например, если ваш сервис пишет в `/var/log/myservice/`, а вы хотите, чтобы он писал в хостовый каталог `/opt/myservice/log/`, напишите в `docker-compose.yaml`

```
services:
  myservice:
    image: ...
    volumes:
      - /opt/myservice/log:/var/log/myservice
```

Лог файлы будут создаваться в `/opt/myservice/log`